# Update or delete value in nested jsonb object

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have two scenarios that I am trying to figure out. I have a jsonb column in a table with a structure like this:

```
   {
    "1": {
        "a": 0.084,
        "b": 0.084,
        "c": 0.084
    },
    "2": {
        "a": 0.078,
        "b": 0.0814,
        "c": 0.078
    },
    "3": {
        "a": 0.0928,
        "b": 0.0975,
        "c": 0.0975
    }
   }
```

If I wanted to change the value of "3":{"b":} how would I go about doing it? I tried looking at functions like ***jsonb_set()***, but that seemed like I would have to copy the entire jsonb object and re-paste it in every time I wanted to update one value.

The second issue I want to solve is if I want to delete the entire "3":{} object, the only solution I can seem to find is using ***jsonb_set()*** again.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_set()` function with the related path `'{3,b}'` in order to `update` :

```
SELECT jsonb_set(jsonb_data, '{3,b}','0.1') 
  FROM tab
```

*where 0.1 is just a sample value*

Use `#-` operator in order to `delete` :

```
SELECT jsonb_data #- '{3}'
  FROM tab
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=5d5518eb265787762607ad28d079226b)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks! That works out really well and does exactly what I need it to. 

Is it possible to do that with multiple values in the same object? Like if I wanted to set the value for A, B and C at the same time? 

Thanks again.

Comment: you're welcome @ChristopherCarlisle. Not possible with multiple values within the same object.